# Mocha, Express test error - "after all" hook error - Object function has no method 'close'

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

Im just getting started with Mocha, testing against a very basic Express 4.0 rest API.

```
describe('API CALL UNIT TESTING', function(){
    var app = require('../../app');
    before(function(){
        app.listen(3000);
    });

    describe('GET', function(){

        it('respond with json', function(done){
            request(app)
                .get('/api/compile')
                .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                .expect(200, done)
                .end(function(e, res){
                    //console.log(res)
                    done();
                })
        })
    });

    after(function() {
        app.close();
    });
});
```

Im getting the following error when running the test:

> 1 passing (48ms)   1 failing
>
> 1) API CALL UNIT TESTING "after all" hook:
>        TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) {
>       app.handle(req, res, next);   } has no method 'close'

Can anyone advise what is causing the "after all" hook error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly the app object does not have a close() method.  You don't actually tell us precisely what app is - but if I recall the express API correctly, you actually call the close() on the object returned from listen(), so perhaps you could try:

```
var server;

before(function(){
    server = app.listen(3000);
});

 ....

after(function() {
    server.close();
});
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Indeed you are correct, close is called on the object returned from listen().